# When filter list, how do I directly view or edit the item when only one match

Tags: admin-on-rest

Using a list with a filter, when filtering if there is only one matching item. Is there a way to view/edit that item by hitting enter rather than using the mouse to click a button in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, what you can do is create a custom Datagrid and check the ids received in componentWillReceiveProps and redirect based on the fact that only one result is returned.

```
const MyDatagrid => ({ids,...props}) => ids.length === 1? <Redirect ..> : <Datagrid {...props} ids={ids}/>
```

Comment: Redirecting like this works, but, i cant go back to the list after viewing the item. I would need to clear the filters or something when opening the single item as otherwise the list just re-opens the item again. Any ideas?

Comment: I think a `history.replace` should suffice.